# shortest path algo unweighted graph

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Just to enhance my java script skills i am trying to develop a pacman game in js. have a grid of 20 by 20 . This grid has 0's and 1's which indicate if there is a wall or a path . Now I want to develop a algo for the demons to follow the pacman .  I am not sure which algorithm should I go for .

So my input to the function will be foo( current position, pacman position,grid,  path)

```
var maze = [            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                        [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
                        [0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0],
                        [0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0],
                        [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],
                        [0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0],
                        [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
                        [0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0],
                        [0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0],
                        [0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0],
                        [1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1],
                        [0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0],
                        [0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0],
                        [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
                        [0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0],
                        [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],
                        [0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0],
                        [0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0],
                        [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
                        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Depth first search - 2D Game map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547295/depth-first-search-2d-game-map)

Answer (score 3):

For unweighted graph you have a several options for finding a shortest path:

- [**BFS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) - simplest solution - the BFS is complete and optimal - it will find the shortest path if such exist.
- [**Bi-Directional BFS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_search) - basically the same, but do BFS from both sides, and end when two BFS meet. It significantly decreases the number of vertices discovered. I explained more about how to do it and why it's good in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7220294/572670).
- Heuristical [**A* Algorithm**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) - it is an informed algorithm, and thus usually faster then the others, but is harder to program. Use an [admissible heuristic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic) with it, like the [manhattan distances](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry).

Personally - I think I'd use BFS in this case - but start from pacman, until you discover all "targets" (demon locations) - it will give you the shortest path from each demon to pacman.

Note that if you have just a few demons and a big board, doing A* several times (once per demon) might be a better solution.

One should probably benchmark it to see which is actually better.

Comment: Do I need to build an adjacency list from the grid ?

Comment: @sameerkarjatkar No, you can use the implicit graph structure and build it on the fly. All you need for it is a method `next(v)` that returns all vertices that can be reached from `v` with one step.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find the shortest path from a source to all vertices, perform a Breadth first search from the source and keep storing the parent of each vertex in a separate array.Following the parent nodes will give you the path from each vertex to its parent.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) also works here. Compared with Breadth-first search, there's no need to store all the leaf nodes when you use DFS. But it is not able to find a solution at times. The input here is not that complex, so I think DFS is good enough.

Also, the A* search algorithm is the best choice, cause it's faster than uninformed search and always complete and optimal. It guarantees the solution is optimal. For a complicated situation, to create a efficient heuristic function really costs. Here, you can use Manhattan distance or Euclidean distance.